# Viewpager , How to switch the current page to another page which is not included in the ViewPager , with keeping the Tablayout at the bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentmanager

First , Sorry for my vague title , 
I really don't know how to describe the problem I met.

I will try to draw a picture to explain.

In the following picture , there is a **ViewPager** with a **TabLayout** pointing to the first page.

[image: viewpager with a tablayout]

so it works like this :

[image]

> And the problem is , How to switch the current page to another page **which is not included in the ViewPager** , with **keeping the Tablayout at the bottom** and pointing to the current tab. Like this:

[image]

In the other words ,

> Is it possible to group several pages(fragments) to a tab?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create custom `FragmentPageAdapter` for your ViewPager. That allows you replacing Tab1's base fragment (*Current Page* on your last picture) with another fragment (*Another Page* on your last picture).
You can do it e.g. after click on button on base fragment.
If you wont to go back to base fragment after click on **Tab 1** you have implement `OnTabSelectedListener` having regard to setup with view pager.

I don't attach any code because I don't know how your code looks like.